# Connecting to Server 2012 Client VDI from Linux based Thin Clients

Tags: windows-server-2012, thin-client, vdi, hyper-v-server-2012

Currently we have set up a test VDI environment that hosts several Windows 7 client computers. We are using the "Personal" desktop option and everything seems to be running fine **except...**

The only way to access the virtual desktops seems to be from either logging into the Remote Desktop Web server that is hosting the file and then opening that .RDP file or Alternatively saving that .RDP file and opening it from another PC.

We have several Linux based HP t5145 thin clients running "Thin Pro" that we were looking to utilize to connect to these VDIs, but I cannot seem to find a way to open the .rdp file or to connect to the VDI through the pool. [The only DIRECT message from Microsoft I could find was here:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh407117.aspx)

> Without the RD Web Access role service to aid discovery, you’ll need
>   to share the RDP files explicitly with all users. Any changes to this
>   access would require a re-dispersal of the RDP file.

So is connecting to client VDI only supported from that darn RDP file? Is there anyway to open that file with rdesktop or another linux alternative? Is there any documentation from Microsoft or HP on the matter? (I couldn't find anything but this sales document that assured me that it was ["Fully Tested, Ready to Run"](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/product_pdfs/4AA4-3901ENW.pdf))

Thanks.

Comment: Open the rdp file with your favorite text editor.  Use the settings you see to configure you thin clients.